# Prove that two balls in $\mathbb{R}^n$ intersect

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Suppose there are balls $B(x_1,0.9)$ and $B(x_2,0.9)$, both contained inside $B(0,1)$, where $x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and the metric is the standard Euclidean distance. How can we show that the balls must intersect? It is somewhat clear in the case $n=2$ (geometrically), but I'm not really sure how to get started proving it in the general case.

Comment: By 'contained inside' I assume you mean $B(x_1,0.9), B(x_2,0.9)\subset B(0,1)$. You just need to find a point $x_3\in B(0,1)$ such that $x_3\in B(x_1,0.9)$ and $x_3\in B(x_2,0.9)$; I can think of a few such points, do you have any guesses/thoughts?

Comment: Also, might be a good idea to find the set $\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n: B(x,0.9)\subset B(0,1)\}$.

Comment: Well, the set is the set of $x$ such that, for all $y$ with $d(x,y) \leq 0.9$, we have $d(y,0) \leq 1$. If $d(x,y) \leq 0.9$ and $d(y,0) \leq 1$, we can deduce $d(x,0) \leq 1.9$, but I'm not sure whether that's helpful or how to further characterise the set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $B(x_{1},0.9)$'s center has a maximum distance from the origin of $1-0.9 = 0.1$, so it must contain the origin. Similarly, $B(x_{2}, 0.9)$ must contain the origin. Thus, $\boxed{B(x_{1},0.9)\text{ and }B(x_{2},0.9) \text{ must intersect.}}$

Comment: How do you formally prove the maximum distance is $0.1$? If you try to use the triangle inequality you get a bound of $1+0.9 = 1.9$.

Comment: Assume that the center of the ball is futher from the origin than $0.1$, say $0.1 + \epsilon$. Then, consider the point inside the ball, $0.9 - \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ away from its center and in the opposite direction from the ball's center as the origin. However, this means the point is $1 + \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ away from the origin, contradiction.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work!