# Two open balls shares a point

Tags: proof-writing, metric-spaces

> Let $X=\mathbb{R}^n$and suppose that d is one of $d_1,d_2,d_\infty$. Suppose we have two balls $B(x_1,0.9), B(x_2,0.9)$, both contained in $B(0,1)$ . Show that they intersect. Is the same true in a general metric space (X,d)?

$d_1(x,y)=\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i - y_i|$, $d_2(x,y)= [\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - y_i)^2]^{0.5}$ and $d_\infty (x,y)=max_{i \in J_{n}} |x_i - y_i|$

**My attempt:**

We need to show that, there exist some point of $X$ Which is in both balls. Let $u \in B(x_1,0.9)$. Then $d(u,x_1) \lt 0.9$. Since both balls contained in $B(0,1)$, we have $d(x_1,0) \lt 1$ & $d(x_2,0) \lt 1$. So, $d(x_1,x_2) \lt 2$. $d(u,x_2) \leq d(x_2,x_1)+d(x_1,u)$ $\Rightarrow$ $d(u,x_2)\lt 2.9$

**Question:** How do I show, for some $u\in B(x_1,0.9)$, $d(u,x_2) \lt 0.9$?

Source of this problem: https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwj1qOKy94z0AhWYqksFHbhICnIQFnoECAIQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcourses-archive.maths.ox.ac.uk%2Fnode%2Fview_material%2F52134&usg=AOvVaw22jUgkNiUgFyOrMHgEtzQ3 (exercise 3)

Comment: Can you please define what the metrics: $d_{1}$, $d_{2}$, $d_{\infty}$ are? Also, in general it is not true.

Comment: You haven't used any information about $d_1$, $d_2$, or $d_{\infty}$. You have to introduce them into the calculations.

Comment: @SNJ I'm sorry for that.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I tired using $d_1$ distance function, but I am getting stuck at the same step as I’m getting in general metric. Can you please show the result(for $d_1$ maybe)or give more hints?

Comment: Maybe you can show that if $r\ge1/2$ and $B(x,r)\subset B(0,1)$ then $B(x,r)$ contains the origin.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3872682/prove-that-two-balls-in-mathbbrn-intersect?rq=1

Comment: @GerryMyerson I give up. I can prove that claim only for $r \geq 1$ (used contradict).

Comment: @SNJ Thank you for link. Unfortunately I find that answer vague. It skip almost everything. I felt, that answer was talking to geometric plane. It left out all detail, including the essential idea which required to proof the claim satisfactorily. I’m sorry if I sound frustrated.

Comment: @user264745 I'm also quite frustrated. Let's look at the "Is it true in a general metric space $(X, d)$?" case, to get a clue and solve it together. Let $B(x, \frac{\epsilon}{2})$ and $B(y, \frac{\epsilon}{2})$, then let $\epsilon = d(x, y)$. Now, by the triangle inequality we have (assuming that the two balls have a point $z$ in common): $\epsilon = d(x, y) \leq d(x, z) + d(z, y) < \epsilon$ is clearly a contradiction. For your specific question, I think a proof by contradiction would be the right approach; however still trying out to find an argument.

Comment: It has already been pointed out to you that this will not be true for every metric $d$, so you need to prove it for $d_1, d_2, d_\infty$ specifically. For $d_2$, if $r > \frac 12$ and $B(x,r) \subset B(0,1)$, let $x' = \frac x{d_2(x,0)}$. $0, x, x'$ are collinear, and $d_2(x',0) = 1$, so $x' \notin B(0,1)$ and therefore not in $B(x,r)$, so $d_2(x, x') \ge r > \frac 12$. If $0 \notin B(x,r)$ then also $d_2(x,0) > \frac 12$ But Euclidean distances on a line are additive. This is a contradiction. (Note that this additive along lines property is specific to $d_2$.)